# Concrete class names for RichFaces 4.x

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am upgrading my Application from RichFaces 3.3.3 to 4.3.3 adn JSF 1.2 to 2.1. Most of the code is dynamic and written in java files instead of jsp. Can anyone direct me where I can find concrete class names for RichFaces new Components like rich:select, a4j:ajax, rich:panel etc.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks
Ankit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [RichFaces Component Reference](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces/docs/4-0_comp_reference.html), there you will find `component-type`, `component-class`, `component-family`, `renderer-type` for each component

Also you may find useful looking into the following files:

```
richfaces-components-ui-4.3.3.Final.jar!/META-INF/a4j.taglib.xml
richfaces-components-ui-4.3.3.Final.jar!/META-INF/rich.taglib.xml
richfaces-components-ui-4.3.3.Final.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
```

There you will find all the information about component classes, renderers, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrey. I opened that website before but I overlooked.